# Have a rule to send email with they get added to specific groups, why does the email get sent if they added to other groups?

Tags: civirules

I set up a rule that sends an email when someone gets added to one the children of a parent group.  It works great.

However, if someone who was added to one of the children groups in the past, gets added some other group that is not one of the children, the email gets sent again even though they weren't just added one of the children.

It seems we have a choice of the individual is (not) in group.  I can maybe see that as useful but in this case I only care if they just got added or removed or deleted, not that are currently in a specified group.

So am I missing something?  Is there some way only get changes to the group status of the contacts in the groups?

Here is a screen shot of my rule
[image]

So this is what happens.

1. A Contact, say John Smith, is added to the group "Online Background Check Required"
2. An email is sent saying John Smith has been added to the group "Online Background Check Required" (So far so good)
3. The same contact is later added to another group.  (Just in case the other group has something odd about it, I tried a few different groups that were recently created.  These other groups are not connected at all to the Background check group.)
4. The email is sent saying John Smith has been added to the group "Online Background Check Required".  (I think this shouldn't happen.)

I took a peak at the code I think is behind the Contact (not) in Group(s) and as far as I can tell it does just that, is the contact in the group.  There doesn't seem to be anything that says look for just added or deleted or removed so every time the check groups trigger fires it looks at that contact and sees that they are in the group.  I'm not sure if the Contact (not) in Group(s) was intended to looking for people just added a group or if it is designed just to see if the contact is in the group.  I can see uses for both.

Of course, it's harder to get the date and time someone was added to or removed from a group but it is there somewhere just not in the group_contact table.

Comment: Can you attach (or send me) a screen shot of the rule you are using and an example of what happens so I can try to replicate it on my local Civirules sandbox?